# Enabling RSS Feeds for a career site

Tags: xml, web-scraping, rss, integration, feed

We are gonna integrate our career site with a 3rd party site like Monster and we are supposed to provide job vacancies by means of `XML` feeds. So that my understanding is we have to configure `RSS` in our site for them to subscribe and pull the data they required. I'm a newbie in this scenario and could anybody help me.

These are the clarification needed.

1. What are the steps to enable `RSS` for a web site? I found that we can use an external tools.
2. Once RSS is enabled will there be any security concerns?
3. Is there a way for a 3rd party to get `XML` feeds from our site without having us to enable a `RSS` like feature?
4. What would be the challenges such as security, validation, integrity and so on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends. You have a system to take some data and express it as HTML. You need to build (or otherwise acquire) a system that will take that data and express it as XML.
2. It's just data. The security concerns are more-or-less the same as HTML
3. If your site doesn't serve XML then nobody get can XML from it.
4. It's just a data format. The challenges are more-or-less the same as for HTML. The only difference is that parsers are less forgiving of errors, so you need proper XML tools and not just some templates that slap strings together.